# Git: How set upstream of a remote branch to another remote branch?

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-flow

I have two remote branches:

```
feature/feature1 //upstreamed to master
```

And the other branch is a *subtask* -> `subtask/subtask1` of `feature/feature1`

I want to set the upstream of `subtask/subtask1` to `feature/feature1`

As there are multiple developers working on the same feature's different subtasks, so the idea is to have a remote feature branch upstreamed to master and to have the subtasks upstreamed to the feature branch.

So once subtasks are reviewed they should get met merged to the feature branch and once all subtasks are completed the feature will merge to master.

It should look like below:

```
master-
       feature1-
                subtask1
                subtask2
```

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Does `subtask/subtask1` is a local branch? And what do you mean "other branch is a subtask -> `subtask/subtask1` of `feature/feature1`"?

Comment: Try to draw a graph showing your intended branch structure

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT, I have updated the description

Comment: @MadPhysicist have added the tree diagram and updated the information

Comment: @ambar I added the answer to change upstreamof the `subtask/subtask1` to track `remotename/feature/feature1`, and you can have a try.

Comment: thanks @MarinaLiu-MSFT  . But this will set the upstream locally, isn't it?

Comment: I'm not sure that there is even a valid question here. Git allows you to make a branch anywhere for any purpose.

Comment: @ambar all commands in git are local except commands which update the repo, like fetch, and pull.

Comment: @ambar Has your problem been solved yet? If yes, can you mark the answer? And it will also benefit others who meet similar questions :)

Answer (score 1):

To set upstream of the branch `subtask/subtask1` to track the remote `feature/feature1` branch, you can use below commands:

```
git checkout subtask/subtask1 
git branch --set-upstream-to=<remoteName>/feature/feature1
```

Such as if the remote name is `origin`, you can use:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/feature/feature1
```

After setting tracking branch, you can use the command `git branch -vv` to double check the relationship between local branches and they're tracking branches.

Comment: this will set the upstream locally, isn't it?

Comment: @ambar Not exactly. the tracking branch is the relationship between local and remoote. Such as on subtask/subtask1 branch, if you execute `git pull/push`, git will pull/push from/to remote feature/feature1 by default.

Answer (score 1):

There is a terminology issue here: a "remote branch" could mean *a named branch stored on the remote* (i.e., in the *other* Git repository), or it could mean *a remote-tracking name stored locally*.

An example of the former is `master`, but not *your* `master`, instead it is *their* `master`.  To manipulate this name you must log in to the machine that hosts that Git repository, or use `git push`.

An example of the latter is `origin/master`: this is *your* name, to do with as you will, except that your Git will automatically update this name from *their* `master` any time you run `git fetch origin`.  Hence your `origin/master` remembers their `master`.

A *remote-tracking name* like `origin/master` *cannot* have an upstream.  While this name is in your repository, it's slaved to someone else's branch name.  You cannot check out a remote-tracking name—if you try, you just get what Git calls a *detached HEAD*, as if you had checked out the commit by its hash ID.  So there is no reason to set an upstream on such a name, and you cannot do it.

A *branch name* like `master` can have *at most one* upstream setting.  The upstream setting determines what Git will use by default when you run `git fetch`, `git merge`, `git rebase`, `git push`, or `git pull` (which is just `git fetch` followed by a second Git command).  The main reasons to set an upstream are so that you *can* run these commands without additional arguments, and so that some Git commands will tell you about any divergence between your branch name and its upstream.

Typically you would set the upstream of a (local) branch name like `master` to its `origin` counterpart, such as `origin/master`; and in fact `git checkout` tends to do this automatically, so that you don't have to set the upstream for each branch—you simply `git checkout feature/feature1` and your Git *creates* your `feature/feature1` from your `origin/feature/feature1`, setting the upstream for your `feature/feature1` to your `origin/feature/feature1`.